# Microsoft Chart Controls in WPF4

Tags: wpf, charts

Have Microsoft Chart Controls been integrated into .NET 4 release of WPF? I've found some statements supporting such claims but i cant find those controls :/ How do I use them in WPF4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This MSDN library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx) gives an overview over the new features in WPF 4. A Chart control is not part of WPF 4.
There is, however, a preview of the chart controls that probably will be released in an upcoming WPF version or service pack. You can download the preview as part of the [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535).